# Debugging in FlashDevelop, app works; executing .exe, app fails

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

When debugging in FlashDevelop everything works in my application.
But when I packaged it with Air, installed it and run it.
It misses it connection to air.
What should I do?

P.S. I'm using FlashDevelop with FlexSDK 4.5.1 en AIR SDK 3.0.

Comment: Oops, apparently I had to run as an Administrator. Now everything works.

Comment: You had to run FlashDevelop as Administrator? Or your EXE?

Comment: I had to run the .exe as an administrator.